# change button background color on click- WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, wkinterfacebutton

Button background is initially white with no background. Need the background to change to the following hex value: #cd9037

```
@IBOutlet weak var zeroTapped: WKInterfaceButton!
@IBAction func ZeroTapped() {
    zeroTapped.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 205, green: 144, blue: 55,alpha: 1.0 ))
    var time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, TIMEOUT)
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.appendValue(0)
    })
}
```

Any body suggest why the following isn't working? Double checked RGI values.

Comment: try testing another RGB color ..does it show?

Comment: Is the view active when you call the function to change the color?

Comment: I tried the following color: zeroTapped.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0,alpha: 1.0 )). Still doesnt work

Comment: @vomako the view is active because when i try to change  an image instead of color self.zeroTapped.setBackgroundImageNamed("keybutton1.png") it works

Comment: Ok I did self.zeroTapped.setBackgroundColor(...). This worked.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been resolved: `self` was missing.

```
self.zeroTapped.setBackgroundColor(...)
```